# How to limit graph so the value doesn't go beyond the graph

Tags: r, graph, statistics

I need help.
I have the following data. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZZFV.png)

And I have a graph that keeps going beyond the graph as I have set the limit of Y axis from 0-4 to get a relative frequency. How do you edit a code so that the graph doesn't go beyond those ylim value = (0,4)?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/95RoG.png)

```
**barplot (cSpecPct, ylab = "%", 
         col="Light Blue",
         main = "Fish Relative Frequency",
         las = 2,
         ylim = c(0,4),
         cex.names = 1.2,
         cex.axis = 1.6,
         cex.lab = 1.2)**
```

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, you include species with percentages greater than 4%, so do you not want to plot them at all? Do you want the percentages relative to the largest value? Or do you want something else.

Comment: Hi, so looking at the image that I posted, the graph goes beyond the y limit of 4, I want them so that it doesn't stretch above 4%.

Comment: If your data goes beyond 4% (which it does) then you cannot display it on a graph that only goes to 4%. What do you want, for example, the Largemouth Bass bar to look like? Do you not want to display it all, filter it out, how would you handle it?

Comment: Before anything, thanks for the help. So I know some of the data goes beyond 4 and thus, not going to display on the graph however, the bar goes beyond 4%, beyond the graph. The ones that goes beyond 4%, I want them to stop them at 4%. Take a look at the image if possible.

Comment: That produces a misleading plot, but if you want it `Max4 <- ifelse(cSpecPct < 4, cSpecPct, 4)` followed by `barplot(Max4)` will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is just modify the data.

```
barplot(ifelse(cSpecPct > 4, 4, cSpecPct), ylab = "%", 
         col="Light Blue",
         main = "Fish Relative Frequency",
         las = 2,
         ylim = c(0,4),
         cex.names = 1.2,
         cex.axis = 1.6,
         cex.lab = 1.2)
```

That being said, this will make it seem like all the species with greater than 4% relative frequency have exactly 4% relative frequency, so I would suggest doing something else to indicate that it is more.

Comment: Gotcha. I was initally thinking of changing that cSpecPct / 100 and ylim = c(0,.4) so it represents a better display but, someone insisted to have that graph on ylim of 4 so that got me into a stubborn mode to know how.. Thanks all for helping me out.